# Meteor Autoform Custom Templates

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-autoform

This is a niche one - hopefully someone has had some experience with this before! Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

### Problem

I'm trying to use Autoform together with Autoform-Semantic-UI and nested custom templates. In the interface, the outer form loads, but when my custom templates load I get console errors referencing that the template cannot access any data, such as:

```
debug.js:41 Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
at afArrayTracker.atInitField [as initField]

Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null
at Object.autoFormGetLabelForField [as getLabelForField]

Exception in template helper: Error: Invalid field name: (not a string)
at Object.getDefs
```

This makes my form only partially rendered!

### Code

client.js has the schema design:

```
Schemas = {};

Template.registerHelper("Schemas", Schemas);

Schemas.MarkingScheme = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      optional: false
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      optional: true
    },
    aspects: {
        type: Array
    },
    'aspects.$': {
      type: Object
    },
    'aspects.$.focus': {
        type: String
    },
    'aspects.$.rubric': {
        type: Array,
        minCount: 1
    },
    'aspects.$.rubric.$': {
      type: Object
    },
    'aspects.$.rubric.$.mark': {
        type: Number
    },
    'aspects.$.rubric.$.criteria': {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    comments: {
        type: [String],
        optional: true
    }
});
```

Here's the template for the form, which works fine:

```
<template name="insertScheme">
  <div class="ui large header">New Marking Scheme</div>
    {{#autoForm schema=Schemas.MarkingScheme id="insertScheme" type="insert"}}
      {{> afQuickField name="name"}}
      {{> afQuickField name="description"}}

      {{> afArrayField name="aspects" template="rubric"}}

      {{> afQuickField name="comments"}}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="centered column">
          <div class="two large ui buttons">
            <button type="reset" class="ui button">Clear</button>
            <div class="or"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="positive ui button">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

Now is where things go south, even though I've reverted to using a near carbon copy of the template used for the semantic-ui autoform package:

```
<template name="afArrayField_rubric">
  <h4 class="ui top attached block header">
    {{afFieldLabelText name=this.atts.name}}
  </h4>
  <div class="ui secondary bottom attached segment">
    {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name=this.atts.name}}
      <div class="ui pointing red basic label">
        {{{afFieldMessage name=this.atts.name}}}
      </div>
    {{/if}}
    {{#afEachArrayItem name=this.atts.name minCount=this.atts.minCount maxCount=this.atts.maxCount}}
      <div class="field autoform-array-item">
        {{#if afArrayFieldHasMoreThanMinimum name=../atts.name minCount=../atts.minCount maxCount=../atts.maxCount}}
          <div class="ui mini red corner label autoform-remove-item">
            <i class="icon minus"></i>
          </div>
        {{/if}}
        {{> afArrayField name=this.name label=false options=afOptionsFromSchema template="aspects"}}
      </div>
    {{/afEachArrayItem}}
    {{#if afArrayFieldHasLessThanMaximum name=this.atts.name minCount=this.atts.minCount maxCount=this.atts.maxCount}}
      <div class="field">
        <div class="ui small green icon button autoform-add-item" data-autoform-field="{{this.atts.name}}" data-autoform-minCount="{{this.atts.minCount}}" data-autoform-maxCount="{{this.atts.maxCount}}">
          <i class="icon plus"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

The idea is that it goes on deeper; but this is as far as we get.

Many thanks for any ideas of things to try!

Comment: did you install Collection2 package?

Comment: I didn't have the package originally, but I gave it an install now. No magical fix; but is there some way I should be using it?

Comment: Collection2 lets you add the object/schema to mongo and it validates automatically.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll have a read up, thanks!